# expo-auth-session, after signin in with Google shown with two apps options

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

so the problem is after signing in with Google through `expo-auth-session`, the device prompted a question and asked me to choose between two apps (both are the same app). If I choose the one on the left it will work fine, but choosing the one on the right will lead to a broken app.

What's the problem? and how to solve this issue?

Here's  my `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "owner": "TEST",
    "name": "TEST",
    "description": "TESTING APP",
    "slug": "test-app",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/something-icon.png",
    "appScheme": "com.test.app",
    "scheme": "com.test.app",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "currentFullName": "@user/test-app",
    "originalFullName": "@user/test-app",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/code-here"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["*/"],
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.test.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon-foreground.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#0D0125"
      },
      "package": "com.test.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you upload into geekzwolf arena"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "testProjectId"
      },
      "apiArena1": "http://localhost:3000/test",
      "apiArena": "https://test.app.com/test"
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start ",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.7.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.3.3",
    "countries-list": "^2.6.1",
    "date-format": "^4.0.13",
    "ethers": "^5.7.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-application": "^4.2.2",
    "expo-asset": "~8.6.1",
    "expo-app-auth": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
    "expo-blur": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.2",
    "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-country-flag": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-simple-accordion": "^1.17.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "semver": "^7.3.8",
    "timediff": "^1.1.1",
    "twrnc": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.7.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "~44.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "prettier": {
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "endOfLine": "lf",
    "insertPragma": false,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "proseWrap": "preserve",
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "requirePragma": false,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was, I used both `expo-app-auth` and `expo-auth-session`. According to [this post](https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-auth-session-two-app-options-on-android/50451), it will create duplicated schemes, hence the two apps. In addition to that, `expo-app-auth` is deprecated in favour of `expo-auth-session`, so there's no reason to have `expo-app-auth` in `package.json` anymore (unless there's specific case where you need it).